# Backspace in select loop

Tags: bash, select

When i use select loop to create a list of options, if i make a mistake during the prompt and want to hit backspace, it doesnt erase the character but displays ^H instead of it.

I know in "read" i can use -e to resolve this, but what do i do in select loop?
Also, CTRL+C to break out of loop doesn't work.
I've created select loop to loop through directories on remote side in menu-like style. It will change directory if directory is selected, but if it's not directory, it will select it as a file to edit.

```
until [[ $DONE == Yes ]]; do
select dir in $(ssh auth1 ls $PUTANJA $ONLYARPA) Nazad; do
        case $dir in
                "Nazad")
                        if [ "$PUTANJA" == "/var/named/chroot/var/named/master" ]; then
                                return
                        else
                                PUTANJA=$(ssh auth1 "cd $PUTANJA; cd ..; pwd")
                        fi
                        ;;
                *)
                        if ssh auth1 "[ -d $PUTANJA/$dir ]"; then
                                PUTANJA=$PUTANJA/$dir
                        else
                                ZONA=$dir
                                DONE=Yes
                        fi
                        ;;
        esac
        break
done
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your terminal is displaying `^H` when you press the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key, chances are your terminal has set the backspace sequence to a different character from what which you are sending.  One of the other most common Backspace characters is `^?`.  Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd>.  But a more useful solution would be to ensure that your terminal settings match your expectations (and inputs).

Comment: Thing is, unless i run a "select" loop, terminal is responding just fine when i use backspace. I'm on Fedora and i use standard Gnome Terminal. If the problem is actually with terminal, how come it works fine on everything else but "select" loop?

I just tried changing "Backspace Key Generates" from Control+H to "Automatic" on gnome-terminal, seems to work fine for now! So thank you ! But still amuses me why it comes up only during select loop